# PHP spl_autload_register alternative way

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am making a pattern for my own project, We knew that this spl_autoload_register turn into all files until it finished. It just returns the class as I know. Let's get into my wish/ Problem!

```
app
 |__ controllers
 |      |__ ctrl-default.php
 |      |__ ctrl-other.php
 |
 |
 index.php
```

In my controllers have classes with the almost same name.

```
// ctrl-default.php
class  ctrl_default{
  //silence is golden...
}

// ctrl-other.php
class  ctrl_other{
  //silence is golden...
}
```

I can not find the class name for the '-' and '_' But I don't want to change my file name or class name.
Is there any possible way to get all the class on my index.php page, without changing the controllers' name? Is there any alternative way of spl_autoload_register()?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an alternative to spl_autoload_register.
For [Autoloader Standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) it is necessary to name the file name as class name.php. It is not a good idea to use different names.

However, you can do everything with the autoloader function.

The following example is used to understand autoloading.
It is not recommended to do this.

Filename: Ctrl-default.php

```
<?php
class  Ctrl_default{
  public function get(){
    return __CLASS__;
  }
}
```

A simple test.

```
<?php

function myautoloader($classname){
  $fileName = str_replace('_','-',$classname).".php";
  require_once($fileName);
}
spl_autoload_register('myautoloader');

$class = new Ctrl_default;
echo $class->get();
```

When new Ctrl_default is executed, PHP determines that the class is not loaded and calls the myautoloader function. The class name Ctrl_default is passed as a parameter.
With str_replace _ is exchanged and ".php" is added. The $ fileName is then "Ctrl-default.php".

In this simple example, both scripts must be in the same directory.